# Complicated Javascript object creation and rewriting issue. Set of Undefined error

Tags: javascript, object, undefined

```
function reworkInfoData(jsonData){
var userData = [];
userData[0] = {
    date: ' ',
    data: []
};
userData[0].data[0] = {
    activity: ' ',
    time: ' '
}
var timeVar = new Date();
for(var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++){
    timeVar = new Date(jsonData[i].date);
    userData[i].date = timeVar.getFullYear() + '.' + timeVar.getMonth() + 
    '.' + timeVar.getDay();
    for(var k = 0; k < jsonData[i].data.length; k++){
        userData[i].data[k] = jsonData[i].data[k];
    }
}
return UserData;}
```

I'm learning node.js, and for studiyng purposes im trying to write something like study loger using express and ejs. This block of code higher was used to rewrite the JSON date string to the pretty looking one. And i keep getting an error

TypeError: Cannot set property 'date' of undefined
at

```
userData[i].date = ...
```

Comment: What is the value of `jsonData`? I suspect that one of the items in the array is `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: Your iterating jsonData but trying to assign to userData. userData only has the one element you added at the start.

Comment: @styfle Im getting value of jsonData from the JSON.parse(fileContent), so it can't be empy or undefined.

Comment: @ste2425 So what is the proper way to create new array of objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your userData array initially has only one object, so if your jsonData has length more than one than, you will get this error since userData[1] or so on is not defined

Try this

```
function reworkInfoData(jsonData){
  var userData = [];
  userData[0] = {
      date: ' ',
      data: []
  };
  userData[0].data[0] = {
      activity: ' ',
      time: ' '
  }
  var timeVar = new Date();
  for(var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++){
      timeVar = new Date(jsonData[i].date);
      if(userData[i]) {
        userData[i].date = timeVar.getFullYear() + '.' + timeVar.getMonth() + 
        '.' + timeVar.getDay();
        for(var k = 0; k < jsonData[i].data.length; k++){
            if(userData[i].data[k]) {
              userData[i].data[k] = jsonData[i].data[k];
            }else {
              userData[i].data.push(jsonData[i].data[k])
            }
        }
      } else {
        var tmp = {};
        tmp.date = timeVar.getFullYear() + '.' + timeVar.getMonth() + 
        '.' + timeVar.getDay();
        for(var k = 0; k < jsonData[i].data.length; k++){
            tmp[i].data.push(jsonData[i].data[k]);
        }
      }
  }
  return UserData;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lot of things are wrong/bad practise the way you have done this.
1.Instead of code below:

```
var userData = [];
userData[0] = {
    date: ' ',
    data: []
};
```

Try:

```
var userData = [];
userData.push({
    date: ' ',
    data: []
});
```

2.You are checking for jsonData value in : `for(var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++)` but you are accessing userData with the iterator. `userData[i].date` this will fail when `userData.length` is lesser than `jsonData.length`. Change your logic to fix this.